# Finding number to make this inequality work

Tags: discrete-mathematics, inequality

I have the following as given:

$p \in (0,1]$, 
$n$ a positive integer

I would like to make the inequality

$$\frac{(np)^k}{k^k} e^{-np} \geq n^{-1/3}$$

true. I am constrained to picking $k \in  (0,n]$, and preferably $k$ should depend on $np$.

Does anyone have ideas on how to go about picking $k$?

Answer (score 1):

The best thing to do is to take the value of $k$ that maximises $\big(\frac{np}{k}\big)^k$. We can find this by differentiating $\log\big(\frac{np}{k}\big)^k$ wrt $k$, to get $\log np-\log k-1$, which vanishes when $k=\frac{np}{e}$. (This is genuinely a maximum.)

So the best we can do is to choose this $k$, making the LHS $e^{np(e^{-1}-1)}$. Unfortunately there is no reason why this should exceed the RHS in general. Certainly if you keep $p$ fixed then for large enough $n$ it does not.